# Exposing 3rd-party controls to the UI Automation framework

Tags: ui-automation

I am using 3rd-party controls in my project. There are quite a few controls, like grid, whose cells are not accessible using UI Automation. I was wondering how can I go about making them accessible?

Comment: 1. Whose 3rd-party controls are you using?
2. What technology is the application (WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms)?
3. What are you using to perform UI Automation (White, Coded UI Tests)?

Comment: Devexpress.Winforms I will code myslef using UI automation,or try out white

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

UI Automation of a WPF Custom Control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165614.aspx